# Не пустой контейнер

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том что есть контейнер, которому со временем может быть присвоена длина 0, но глобальный контейнер сохраняет эти элементы будто они имеют длину хотя их обнулили (нужно чтобы произошло так что глобальный контейнер уменьшился в размерах).

Вот код:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.global{
  background:blue;
}
.main{
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:0%; /// Можно менять это значение, контейнер будет как бы все равно держать в уме эти блоки
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.square{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">hello!</div>
```

Не знаю как задать правильно вопрос (пусть переименуют если нужно будет).

P.S Что-то мне подсказывает, что мою проблему решить нельзя

Comment: Под "длиной" имеется в виду ширина или высота?

Comment: Если убрать оба <div class="square"></div>, то .global тоже исчезнет.

Comment: @labris ширина, это и так понятно что глобал исчезнет ведь физически этих контейнеров ведь нет, а так они присутствуют хоть в том виде что дочерний контейнер говорит что я вас не показываю, но вы есть. Прям как в том анекдоте: "Ты видишь суслика? И я нет, а он есть."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени `width:0%;` на `width:0px;`

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.global{
  background:blue;
}
.main{
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:0px; /// Можно менять это значение, контейнер будет как бы все равно держать в уме эти блоки
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.square{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">hello!</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем причина?

Comment: какая?.........

Comment: С % есть невидимый блок, а с px его нет

Comment: Длина глобального auto

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html - 10.2  `width
   Value:     Initial:   auto`

Comment: Не понимаю что вы этим хотите сказать? Можно человеческим языком, а не набором слов вырванных из разных контекстов

Comment: Родительский div с auto не считает свою длину по длине в % от дочернего main, а по максимальным абсолютным размерам всех внутренних. Если дочерний ограничен не % а именно px то он задаёт ограничение максимального размера внутренних. Это видно на картинках

Comment: Выходит это такая особенность, запомним!